# Access and use $HOME environment for setting the path for a new font

Tags: macros, fontspec, paths, environment-variables, kpathsea

I want to use a font I just downloaded for a  document class I created. This document class will be used on other workstations so I would like the path of the font not to be "hardcoded" but rather to depend on the workstation.

For now I am not using the template but rather just testing with `\documentclass{article}`.
So I tested the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{comment}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\getenv}{om}
 {
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich ~ --var-value ~ #2 } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
   }
   {
    \tl_set_eq:NN #1 \l_tmpa_tl
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\variable}{\getenv[\HOME]{HOME}\HOME}
\newcommand{\mypath}{\variable/texmf/tex/latex/local/template/Barlow/}

\begin{document}

Written things..

\mypath

\end{document}
```

It seems to work: it is written on the pdf:

```
Written things..
/home/myname/texmf/tex/latex/local/template/Barlow/
```

However it does not work if I try to set the new font with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{comment}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\getenv}{om}
 {
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich ~ --var-value ~ #2 } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
   }
   {
    \tl_set_eq:NN #1 \l_tmpa_tl
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\variable}{\getenv[\HOME]{HOME}\HOME}
\newcommand{\mypath}{\variable/texmf/tex/latex/local/template/Barlow/}

\setmainfont{Barlow}
[Path=\mypath,
Extension= .ttf,
UprightFont= *-Regular,
ItalicFont= *-Italic,
BoldFont= *-Bold,
BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic]

\begin{document}

Written things..

\mypath

\end{document}
```

It prints the following errors:

```
\variable ->\getenv [\HOME 
                           ]{HOME}\HOME 
l.31 BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic]
                                   
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\variable ->\getenv [\HOME ]{HOME}\HOME 
                                        
l.31 BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic]
                                   
? 
kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid filename `[', contains '['
(|kpsewhich --var-value HOME)

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

How can I transform this variable so it can be understood by `Path=\mypath`? Or how can I set the path name in a generic way so that this document can run on other workstations?

Comment: `\getenv` is not expandable, so you can't put it in something that should be “just text”, like a file path.  You need to execute it first, then put `\HOME` in the string.  Try `\getenv[\HOME]{HOME}` then `\newcommand{\mypath}{\HOME/texmf/tex/latex/local/beebryte_template/Barlow/}`, and then load the font

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik it worked, thank you very much!

Comment: By the way, you don’t want to use `fontenc` if you’re also using `fontspec` (outside some weird special cases). The `fontenc` package sets up some legacy 8-bit font encodings obsoleted by Unicode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `\getenv` is not expandable (mainly because it does assignments, which are never expandable), which means you can't put it where TeX expects “just text”.  To get your code to work you need to first call `\getenv`, and then use the result (which will be “just text”) in the path variable.  Something along these lines:

```latex
% First store the environment variable `$HOME` in `\HOME`
\getenv[\HOME]{HOME}
% then build the path with `\HOME` (which is a string)
\newcommand{\mypath}{\HOME/texmf/tex/latex/local/template/Barlow/}
% then you can use that in the path to the font
\setmainfont{Barlow}
[Path=\mypath,
...
```

A few comments:

- With Unicode engines and `fontspec` you usually don't need (and it's usually a bad idea) to use `fontenc` (though in your case you had it before `fontspec`, so it didn't do much harm);
- I'd suggest using `TEXMFHOME` instead of `HOME`: that will take into account if you have `texmf` somewhere other than the standard path;
- I added `\cctab_select:N \c_str_cctab` in the call to `\sys_get_shell:nnN` to avoid problems with special characters in the path (better be on the safe side).

Here's the compilable code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\getenv}{om}
  {
    \sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich ~ --var-value ~ #2 }
      { \cctab_select:N \c_str_cctab } \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_tmpa_tl
    \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
      { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
      { \tl_set_eq:NN #1 \l_tmpa_tl }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% set \TEXMFHOME
\getenv[\TEXMFHOME]{TEXMFHOME}

\newcommand{\mypath}{\TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/local/template/Barlow/}

\setmainfont{Barlow}
[Path=\mypath,
Extension= .ttf,
UprightFont= *-Regular,
ItalicFont= *-Italic,
BoldFont= *-Bold,
BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic]

\begin{document}

Written things..

\mypath

\end{document}
```

---

If you're on TeX Live 2019 or earlier (please update to a more recent version or) replace:

```latex
    \sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich ~ --var-value ~ #2 }
      { \cctab_select:N \c_str_cctab } \l_tmpa_tl
```

by

```latex
    \sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich ~ --var-value ~ #2 }
      {
        \int_set:Nn \tex_endlinechar:D { -1 }
        \int_step_inline:nnn { 0 } { 127 }
          { \char_set_catcode_other:n {##1} }
        \char_set_catcode_space:n { 32 }
      }
      \l_tmpa_tl
```

Comment: Is this code only valid after a certain version? I get `2023-05-19T17:40:36.7420712Z <argument> ...{\c__sys_marker_tl }\cctab_select:N
                                                   \c_str_cctab \scan_stop: \...
\getenv[\VERSION]{VERSION}`  (VERSION is defined).  LaTeX version information: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)` `LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2` `L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>`). (Locally the code works, but here teh version is up to date, the version I show is on GitHub Actions).

Comment: @albert I'm not 100% sure, but I think `cctab` was implemented at some time in 2019, so it should work.  Can you show the complete log file, please?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, the complete log file can be found at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/actions/runs/5026776746/jobs/9015453993 (maybe a bit inconvenient but the best I can do).

Comment: @albert catcode tables (`cctab`) were added in July 2020, so your TeX Live 2019 doesn't have it (you should update!).  Meanwhile, you can replace `\cctab_select:N \c_str_cctab` by `\int_set:Nn \tex_endlinechar:D { -1 }
\int_step_inline:nnn { 0 } { 127 } { \char_set_catcode_other:n {##1} }
\char_set_catcode_space:n { 32 }` to get the same effect

Comment: Thanks for the information. All very god to know (info could maybe added to your answer). Regarding the update I agree but it is out of my hands, it is on Github Actions.

Comment: @albert Github Actions doesn't choose any particular TeX Live version.  If you are the owner of the repository, you can convince Actions to update to a more recent system.  I'm dumb on that area, but take a look at the setup in the latex3/latex2e repository:  we have it set up such that TeX Live is updated every time a test is run

Comment: It is indeed probably possible to update, we use the default version as provided by the OS (e.g. `sudo apt-get install texlive texlive-latex-recommended texlive-extra-utils texlive-latex-extra texlive-font-utils`). We would encounter similar problems when users would build this part of the documentation (as they might have also an older version of LaTeX installed on their, work, computer). We created already a workaround for the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have an XY-problem here.

You can put your font files in a subdirectory of the project folder, such as `fonts/`, and then add the option `Path = ./fonts/ ,`.  You can then distribute the font files along with the source, as an archive, and be sure you are using the same version of the font in the future.  This should be portable to any TeX distribution on any operating system.

You seem to want to put the files in your `TEXMFHOME` tree, which you would retrieve with `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFHOME`.  Files here should not require a `Path=` option; this tree is searched automatically.  On distributions other than TeX Live, you can set a `TEXINPUTS` environment variable.

If you don’t want to waste any of the hundreds of gigabytes of disk space you have in 2021 on an extra copy of the font files, you can put links there instead.  You can even **attempt** to automate this as a script, something like this (untested, might fail silently):

```shell
#!/bin/sh
md ./fonts
chmod 755 ./fonts
ln -s $(fc-match --format="%{file}" "Barlow-Regular.ttf") ./fonts/Barlow-Regular.ttf
ln -s $(fc-match --format="%{file}" "Barlow-Bold.ttf") ./fonts/Barlow-Bold.ttf
ln -s $(fc-match --format="%{file}" "Barlow-Italic.ttf") ./fonts/Barlow-Italic.ttf
ln -s $(fc-match --format="%{file}" "Barlow-BoldItalic.ttf") ./fonts/Barlow-BoldItalic.ttf
ls -al ./fonts/Barlow*
```

You can also put all the font options in a file in your project directory named `Barlow.fontspec`:

```
\defaultfontfeatures[Barlow]{
  Path = ./fonts/ , % Comment this out to use the local files instead.
  Extension = .ttf ,
  UprightFont = *-Regular ,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic ,
  BoldFont = *-Bold ,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic }
```

This enables you to use `\setmainfont{Barlow}` and `\newfontfamily\BarlowBlue{Barlow}[Color=NavyBlue]` in your document, and edit only the `.fontspec` file when you need to update the font.

You could also have the user install them in their own font path (such as `~/.fonts/` and sometimes `~/.local/share/fonts/` in Linux), a system directory such as `/usr/local/share/fonts`, a subdirectory of the local TeX tree (see `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL`), or of the user TeX tree (`kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFHOME`).  TrueType or OpenType fonts in any of these locations do not require the `Path=` option on Linux.